# Custom Icons do not load on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add custom icons to a google map. However, when I add the code creating the custom icon, the custom icons do not load on the map. Any idea why? An easy method of rectifying the problem?

Here is my code sample

```
function initMap() {
  // specify where the map is centered
  var myLatLng = {lat: 37.77493, lng: -122.419416};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 12
  });

  $.get("/data", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    placeMarkers(data, map);
  });
}

// Create a marker
function placeMarkers(data, map){
  var icon = {
    url:'http://www.arclightbrewing.com/files/Food%20Truck%20Court.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
  };

  var shape = {
  coord: [16, 0, 0, 16, 16, 45, 32 , 16],
  type: 'poly'
  };

  var locations = data["locations"];
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var loc = locations[i]
    ,  lat = loc["latitude"]
    ,  lng = loc["longitude"];

    if (lat && lng){
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat:parseFloat(lat), lng:parseFloat(lng)},
        map:map,
        icon:icon,
        shape:shape
      });
    }
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your icon definition is not correct.  This works for me:

```
var icon = {
  url: 'http://www.arclightbrewing.com/files/Food%20Truck%20Court.png',
  size: new google.maps.Size(488,349),      // original image size
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(64, 40), // desired image size
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 40)
};
```

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Icon)

> scaledSize | Type:  Size
>
> The size of the entire image after scaling, if any. Use this property to stretch/shrink an image or a sprite.

(you don't need to tell it the actual size, although you can)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aLL9zdq/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  // specify where the map is centered
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 37.77493,
    lng: -122.419416
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 12
  });

  // $.get("/data", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  placeMarkers(data, map);
  // });
}

// Create a marker
function placeMarkers(data, map) {
  var icon = {
    url: 'http://www.arclightbrewing.com/files/Food%20Truck%20Court.png',
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(64, 40),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 40)
  };

  var shape = {
    coord: [16, 0, 0, 16, 16, 45, 32, 16],
    type: 'poly'
  };

  var locations = data["locations"];
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var loc = locations[i],
      lat = loc["latitude"],
      lng = loc["longitude"];

    if (lat && lng) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: parseFloat(lat),
          lng: parseFloat(lng)
        },
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        shape: shape
      });
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
var data = {
  locations: [{
    latitude: 37.7598648,
    longitude: -122.4147977,
    name: "Mission District, San Francisco, CA, USA"
  }, {
    latitude: 37.7591221,
    longitude: -122.3895378,
    name: "Dogpatch, San Francisco, CA, USA"
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```